# Use model of different project in the same solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, model, controller

This might be a respeat of the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/638699/807223) but I did not find any working answer.

Say I have project1 which uses the model model1. I create a new project, project2, in the same solution and I want to  use the model1 in a view of project2.
is this possible and how do I call this model in my view and controller of project2?

Comment: Do you want the model and controller between both projects to *always* be *exactly* the same?

Comment: Yes please. I just want to have to set the model only in one project and make it available in the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why could you not move your models into a third class assembly that is referenced by both of your client projects?  This way your model truly is defined once and can be used by both projects.

Doing it the way that Erik recommends would result in duplicate source files compiled into each project independently rather than truly sharing the same codebase based on a referenced assembly.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "third class assembly"? Is this class supposed to be created in either one of the projects?

Comment: Within your solution, you would have 3 projects defined.  2 would be your end websites, and then a third project would be just a "class library" that would contain plain POCO objects to be used as your models.  Both of your web projects would then reference this class library and use the models from that namespace.

Comment: So after creating the project of type "Class Library", do I do ahead a create new classes in it that will serve as models? and how do I reference these models in my projects 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, your models will exist within the class library project, and NOT within the web project.  Then from each of your web projects, you would add a project reference back to the models assembly. Details on this can be found on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you. One more ques. is it possible to make a database connection in the library?

Comment: It is absolutely possible, but I would typically shy away from that type of behavior  I personally prefer to have a greater separation from my web and service/database backend. I typically do not like the web interacting with DB directly and have services in the middle.  These services hit the database and return DTO objects which are in turn converted to the view model for the web.  This is a much larger topic however, good discussion here: http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2010/03/06/a-few-thoughts-on-ddd-dtos-view-models-cqs-repositories-and-separation-of-concerns.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I created the models in the library and added references to the library project in reference folder of my foreign projects. How will I reference the model of the library in the foreign view?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21786/discussion-between-jpo-and-mklinker)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure on the purpose of the model that you want to share (it would be nice if you gave us a bit more details on how it will be used), but to share just the model you can create a new project called SharedModels in the same solution where the your projects 1 and 2 are and then reference SharedModels project in both of them.

Comment: But how do i do the referencing?

Comment: In the project where you want to have the reference Right click on the `References` -> `Add Reference...` -> select `Project` under `Solution` on the left -> select the common project

Comment: Say my model name in the new porject is model1. After doing what you suggested, how do I reference that in my view?

Comment: Just like you specify a model for a view in any situation... `@model [namespace].[model name]`. Here is the thing though. What you are asking is highly uncommon and I never had to do anything like that. The chances are, whatever you are doing, you are doing it wrong. I suggest you start with the description of what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have several project which use the same model and I do not want to recreate the model each time, but simply link to a main model. The models also need to connect to a database

Comment: As I thought, you aren't doing it right. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033939/best-practice-for-following-the-view-model-pattern) question and at the accepted answer. The issue with what you are doing is separation of concerns between View Model and Domain Model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21790/discussion-between-jpo-and-dmitry)